# Check all checkboxes not working in wamp

Tags: javascript, html

I was looking for check all checkboxes and found the answer but as i copied the code from fiddle demo to a normal html page and execute the code in WAMP server its not working.

Here is the code:

```
        <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
     <head>
      <title> check all</title>
      <script type="text/javascript">

    $('.chk_boxes').click(function(){
    var chk = $(this).attr('checked')?true:false;
    $('.chk_boxes1').attr('checked',chk);
    });


    </script>

     </head>
     <body>


         <form>
           <table>
                 <tr class="table_head_seperator">
                    <td class="grid_info" width="32px" bgcolor="#f6f6f6"><input type="checkbox" class="chk_boxes1" name="to_delete[<?PHP echo $entry['id'] ?>]"  /></td>
                    <td class="grid_info" width="160px" bgcolor="#eeeeee"><span class="country_name">user name</span></td>

                    <td class="grid_info" width="130px" bgcolor="#eeeeee"><span class="country_name">date created</span></td>
                    <td class="grid_info" width="100px" bgcolor="#f6f6f6"><span class="country_name">username</span></td>
    </tr>
               <tr class="table_head_seperator">
                    <td class="grid_info" width="32px" bgcolor="#f6f6f6"><input type="checkbox" class="chk_boxes1" name="to_delete[<?PHP echo $entry['id'] ?>]"  /></td>
                    <td class="grid_info" width="160px" bgcolor="#eeeeee"><span class="country_name">user name</span></td>

                    <td class="grid_info" width="130px" bgcolor="#eeeeee"><span class="country_name">date created</span></td>
                    <td class="grid_info" width="100px" bgcolor="#f6f6f6"><span class="country_name">username</span></td>
    </tr><tr class="table_head_seperator">
                    <td class="grid_info" width="32px" bgcolor="#f6f6f6"><input type="checkbox" class="chk_boxes1" name="to_delete[<?PHP echo $entry['id'] ?>]"  /></td>
                    <td class="grid_info" width="160px" bgcolor="#eeeeee"><span class="country_name">user name</span></td>

                    <td class="grid_info" width="130px" bgcolor="#eeeeee"><span class="country_name">date created</span></td>
                    <td class="grid_info" width="100px" bgcolor="#f6f6f6"><span class="country_name">username</span></td>
    </tr>
             </table>



    <input type="checkbox" class="chk_boxes" label="check all"  />check all
    </form>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What error do you get? What debugging have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would seem simpler:

```
$('.chk_boxes').click(function(){
    $('.chk_boxes1').prop('checked',$(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

Note that attr is NOT the same as prop

EDIT: now you probably also want to manage the click all one:(also enhanced to handle the problem of setting via code or some other way...using change not click event.

```
$('.chk_boxes').change(function () {
    $('.chk_boxes1').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});
$('.chk_boxes1').change(function () {
        $('.chk_boxes').prop('checked', ($('.chk_boxes1').length == $('.chk_boxes1:checked').length) );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to include a jquery library for this to work

include just after the `</title>`

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Example:

```
<title> check all</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {

$('.chk_boxes').on('click',function(){

    var chk = false;
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
        chk = true;
    }
    $('.chk_boxes1').attr('checked',chk);
});


});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks but even that did not help

Comment: see my edit - it should have been wrapped in a ready function

Comment: yes i tried that from other threads before posting this question.. :)

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6689861/check-all-checkboxes) this is the same thing i am trying.. it was demonstrated in fiddle and i copied it and tried on wamp