# Check all Checkboxes using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have button on my web page, and when this button is clicked I want to select all of the green check boxes in each row of my table.

I am unsure of the logic for this and would appreciate some help

This is my table:

```js
$.each(JSON.parse(result), function (i, item) {
    var row = i + 1;

    $("#mainData").append(
        "<tr>" +
        "<td id='process_" + row + "'" + ">" + item.Process + "</td>" +
        "<td id='checks_" + row + "'" + ">" + item.Checks + "</td>" +
        "<td>" +

        "<div class='btn-group' data-toggle='buttons'" + ">" +

        "<label class='btn btn-success'" + ">" +
        "<input type='checkbox' name='colours' id='green_" + row + "'" + ">" +
        "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'" + "></span>" +
        "</label>" +

        "<label class='btn btn-warning'" + ">" +
        "<input type='checkbox' name='colours' id='yellow_" + row + "'" + ">" +
        "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'" + "></span>" +
        "</label>" +


        "<label class='btn btn-danger'" + ">" +
        "<input type='checkbox' name='colours' id='red_" + row + "'" + ">" +
        "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'" + "></span>" +
        "</label>" +


        "<label class='btn btn-default'" + ">" +
        "<input type='checkbox' name='colours' id='grey_" + row + "'" + ">" +
        "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'" + "></span>" +
        "</label>" +

        "</td>" +
        "<td><textarea id=" + "'" + "comments_" + row + "'" + "type='text' placeholder='' class='form-control input-md'/></td>" +

        "</tr>");
});
```

this is my select all button

```js
 $('#SelectAll').click(function () {

    var rowCount = $('#mainData >tr').length;

    var i;

    for (i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++) {

        $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
    }
});
```

Comment: [check it out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6689908/4770813)

Comment: Instead of using numerated ids use a class: `<input type="checkbox" class="green" />` (the same for the other ids) -> `$(".class").prop(...)`

Comment: You can use `$("input[name='colours']").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));` No need for a loop

Comment: eddie - this didnt work, i only want the ones with id = green to be checked

Comment: try to understand how the selectors in your jQuery constructor work. Right now your loop repeatedly sets the "checked" property of _all_ the checkboxes to the same value, because `$("input:checkbox")` selects all checkboxes on the page simultaneously, and then applies the "checked" property to all of them at once. As others have said, because the selector can make the statement apply to multiple elements at once, you don't really need the loop. Just make it more targeted by giving all the checkboxes a class according to their colour and then using  e.g. `$(".green")` to select them.

Answer (score 2):

The best approach for this is to have a common class. But in case you can't, you can use jQuery wildcard selector like `[id^=green]` This will select all elements with id starting with `green`

```js
$('#SelectAll').click(function() {
  //This will select all inputs with id starting with green
  $("input[id^='green']").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="SelectAll"> Select All Green<br />
<input type="checkbox" name='colours' id='green_1'>Green 1<br />
<input type="checkbox" name='colours' id='green_2'>Green 2<br />
<input type="checkbox" name='colours' id='blue_1'>Blue 1<br />
<input type="checkbox" name='colours' id='blue_2'>Blue 2<br />
<input type="checkbox" name='colours' id='red_1'>Red 1<br />
```

Comment: What do you mean by *this hasnt worked*? Any errors? Restrictions?

Comment: $('#SelectAll').click(function () {

                debugger;

                $("input[id^=green]").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
              
            });

Comment: Clear your cache? Can you post an html of your checkbox?

Comment: <input type="checkbox" name="colours" id="green_1">

Comment: It should work. There is something else in your code that giving you an error. Are you able to `console.log` inside the click function?

Comment: would it be im using <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

Comment: @user1483145 it works in the code snippet above, if you run it. If it doesn't work for you in your environment, play spot the difference between your version and Eddie's. His suggestion is clearly good and works nicely.

Comment: yeah i will have to look a this, think it might have something to do with the jquery library im using - im using an older version

Comment: @user1483145 well try that first, but I don't think the differences between the two versions would include something as core as this